# Can someone help me fully understand this nested loop?

Tags: c, loops, nested-loops

So I have generally understood looping pretty well, although my main concern lies with nested loops. I have provided an example from by book here:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void)
{
    int i, j;                           /* loop control variables */

    printf("           i    j\n");      /* prints column labels */

    for (i = 1;  i < 4;  ++i) {         /* heading of outer for loop */
        printf("Outer %6d\n", i);
        for (j = 0;  j < i;  ++j) {     /* heading of inner loop */
            printf("  Inner %9d\n", j);
        }   /* end of inner loop */
    }   /* end of outer loop */

    return (0);
}
```

The expected output is given as:

```
           i    j
Outer      1
  Inner         0
Outer      2
  Inner         0
  Inner         1
Outer      3
  Inner         0
  Inner         1
  Inner         2
```

My book does not do a great job at explaining how these loops work, and rather just shows us the code and the output.

Why does it start by only printing `i`, then `j`, then printing the incremented `i`, but then start `j` over again?

I want to be able to understand this concept so I can fully utilize it when I need it, and I am having trouble finding answers online.

Thanks.

Comment: This is an ideal opportunity to learn how to use the debugger, so you can step through the code line by line. I think that should make it pretty clear

Comment: also a good opportunity to learn how to cut-n-paste your text instead of inserting an image.  Don't insert images of your program.

Comment: Bryan, @Serge is correct in that code images are usually frowned upon here (though some of us give a little leeway if the code is small and we don't have to type it in to debug it). Just something to keep in mind for next time. For now, I've replaced your image with some textual code (and output) to make it less likely it will get closed - I apparently have a lot of time on my hands today :-)

Comment: Bryan, be sure to visit the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what should I do when someone answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire inner loop runs once for every *single* iteration of the outer loop. That inner loop *includes* the initialisation of `j` to `0`, and the printing and incrementing of it up to, but not including, the current `i` (from the outer loop).

So, for the first outer iteration where `i` is `1`, `j` will run from `0` to `0` (all ranges of `j` in this answer are inclusive at both ends). The second outer iteration has `i` equal to `2`, so `j` will run from `0` to `1`.

And so on, up to the final outer iteration where `i` is `3`. In that case, `j` will run from `0` to `2`. Had you added *more* iterations to the outer loop, such as:

```cpp
for (i = 1; i < somethingBiggerThanFour; i++)
```

then you would see something like:

```
Outer         4
  Inner           0
  Inner           1
  Inner           2
  Inner           3
Outer         5
  Inner           0
  Inner           1
  Inner           2
  Inner           3
  Inner           4
... and so on ...
```

In summary, you get:

- `i == 1, j == 0`.
- `i == 2, j == 0, 1`.
- `i == 3, j == 0, 1, 2`.
- `i == 4, j == 0, 1, 2, 3`.
- `i == 5, j == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4`.
- `i == 6, j == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5`.
- `i == 7, j == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`.
- `i == 8, j == 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7`.
- and on and on and on, depending on the outer loop.